# Minimum value of expression $\displaystyle \sqrt{16b^4+(b-33)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Finding point $P(a,b)$ on parabola $x=4y^2$ whose distance from the point $Q(0,33)$ is minimum and also find that minimum distance

What I try : Let coordinate of point $P$ be $(4b^2,b)$ because point $P(a,b)$ lies on $x=4y^2$

So we have $\displaystyle PQ=\sqrt{(4b^2)^2+(b-33)^2}\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg(4b^2+b-33\bigg)=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg[\bigg(b+\frac{1}{8}\bigg)^2-\frac{527}{64}\bigg]\geq -\frac{527}{4\sqrt{2}}$

i.e minimum occur when $\displaystyle b=-\frac{1}{8}$

But i did not understand why minimum value is negative.

Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Note : Above we have used Inequality

$$\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\geq \bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)^2$$

Comment: $b=-\frac18$ makes the second inequality you used to be an equality, not the first.  Hence the negative "minimum value"  you got is just an unachievable lower bound. For it to be the minimum $|PQ|$ must achieve that value for $b=-\frac18$, which it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks  Macavity got it. Can you please tell me How can i correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of $b$ is the same if we are searching the minimum of
$$P(b)=16b^4+b^2-66b+1089$$

The derivaitive, respect to $b$ is
$$P'(b)=64b^3+2b-66$$
And the derivative of this is
$$192b^2+2$$
which has no zeros and it is positive, meaning that $P'$ has only one root, and it is not zero, and that $P$ is convex everywhere. So $P(b)$ has only one minimum.

Since $P'(1)=0$, the minimum of $P$ is $P(1)=1040$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We can directly look at when $|PQ|^2$ is minimised, using univariate calculus or:
$$(4b^2)^2+(b-33)^2=(b-1)^2(16b^2+32b+49)+1040$$

Comment: can you please Tell me the process How you have Write Right Side.

Comment: Testing whether a polynomial factors (with integer roots) or has a nice sum of squares representation is often a worthwhile quick check.  In this case as there would be a minimum distance around low values of $y$, factoring $p(x)-p(1)$ and noticing the double root helped.  OTOH if you prefer a well structured process, the calculus route is for you instead.

Answer (score 2):

We introduce a new $\color{#c00}{\alpha}$ variable, to get the minimum of $P(b):={16b^4+(b-33)^2}$ .

---

Let $\alpha>0$ . Then aplying the AM-GM inequality, we have :

$$
\begin{align}&16b^4+\alpha^2≥8b^2\alpha\\
\implies&16b^4≥8b^2\alpha-\alpha^2
\end{align}
$$

This leads to the following quadratic respect to the variable $\color{#c00}{b}$ :

$$
\small {\begin{align}P(b)&≥8b^2\alpha+(b-33)^2-\alpha^2\\
&=\color{#c00}{b^2}(8\alpha+1)-66\color{#c00}{b}+(33^2-\alpha^2)\\
&=Q(b)\end{align}}
$$

Then, the standard *completing the square* yields :

$$
\small{\begin{align}Q(b):=(8\alpha+1)\left(b-\frac {33}{8\alpha+1}\right)^2-\frac {\Delta_b}{4(8\alpha+1)}
\end{align}}
$$

Thus, we reduce the problem to finding the minimum of $Q(b)$, which is equivalent to determine when the equality case occurs :

$$
\begin{align}\begin{cases}\alpha=4b^2, \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\text{by AM-GM}\\
b=\dfrac {33}{8\alpha+1}, \thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\text {by Discriminant}\end{cases}\end{align}
$$

The above system of equations yields :

$$
\begin{align}0&=32b^3+b-33\\
&=33b^3-b^3+b-33\\
&=33(b^3-1)-(b^3-b)\\
&=\small{33(b-1)(b^2+b+1)-b(b-1)(b+1)}\\
&=(b-1)\underbrace{(32b^2+32b+33)}_{\Delta_b\thinspace<\thinspace 0}
\end{align}
$$

Finally, we obtain the equality case $b=1$, which leads to the final conclusion :

$$
\begin{align}P(b):&=16b^4+(b-33)^2\\
&≥33b^2-66b+1073\\
&=33(b-1)^2+1040\\
&≥1040\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\tiny{\blacksquare}\end{align}
$$

Comment: Nice way Lone student. I got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Finding point $P(a,b)$ on parabola $x=4y^2$ whose distance from the point $Q(0,33)$ is minimum and also find that minimum distance

Let us find $b$ such that the slope of the line passing through $(4b^2,b)$ and $(0,33)$ is equal to the slope of the normal at $(4b^2,b)$.

From $x=4y^2$, we get $1=8yy'$. So, the slope of the normal at $(4b^2,b)$ is given by $-8b$.

So, we have $\frac{b-33}{4b^2-0}=-8b$, i.e. $32b^3+b-33=0$ which can be written as $(b-1)\underbrace{(32b^2+32b+33)}_{\text{positive}}=0$. So, we get $b=1$.

The equation of the tangent line at $(4,1)$ is $y=\frac x8+\frac 12$. Also, the equation of the parabola with $y\ge 0$ is $y=\frac{\sqrt x}{2}$. Now, for every $x\ge 0$, $\frac x8+\frac 12\ge \frac{\sqrt x}{2}$ holds since this is equivalent to $(\sqrt x-2)^2\ge 0$ whose equality is attained only when $x=4$.

So, the point we want is $\color{red}{(4,1)}$, and the minimum distance is $\sqrt{(4-0)^2+(1-33)^2}=\color{red}{4\sqrt{65}}$.

Answer (score 1):

We seek a value $m$ for which the polynomial

$16b^4+(b-33)^2-m=16b^4+b^2-66b+1089-m$

has a doule zero (where the polynomial touches but foes not cross the horizontal axis) at some point $b=b_0$. The smallest $m$ satisfying this condition is the minimum value.

We render the factorization

$16b^4+b^2-66b+1089-m=(b-b_0)^2(16b^2+\alpha_1 b+\alpha_0)).$

Expanding right side and matching cubic, quadratic and lear terms in that order yields

$\alpha_1=32b_0$

$1=-\alpha_0-2\alpha_1b_0+16b_0^2\implies \alpha_0=2\alpha_1b_0-16b_0^2-1=48b_0^2-1$

$-2b_0\alpha_0+b_0^2\alpha_1=-66\implies \color{blue}{64b_0^3+2b_0-66=0}.$

The blue equation is the "zero derivative condition" which we derived for this polynomial minimization without calculus. Clearly $b_0=1$ is a root. Then factoring gives

$2(b_0-1)(32b_0^2+32b_0+33)=0,$

where the quadratic term has a negative discriminant and thus no more real roots. So the minimal distance must occur at $y=b_0=1,x=4y^2=4$ and we calcuate $m=1040$, thus the distance is $\sqrt{m}=4\sqrt{65}$.

Comment: We seek a value $m$ for which the polynomial has a double zero. Can you give a proof, without calculus?

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM $$16b^4+(b-33)^2=16b^4+(b-1-32)^2=16b^4+(b-1)^2-64(b-1)+1024\geq$$
$$\geq16b^4-64(b-1)+1024=16(b^4-4b+3)+1040\geq16\left(4\sqrt[4]{b^4\cdot1^3}-4b\right)+1040=$$
$$=64\left(|b|-b\right)+1040\geq1040.$$
The equality occurs for $b=1$ and since $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ increases, we obtain: $$\min\sqrt{16b^4+(b-33)^2}=\sqrt{1040}.$$

Comment: Let's not fool anyone by using AmGm after knowing $b = 1$ in advance

Comment: @User  Stop with your trolling.

Comment: I respectfully told you the truth.  Accept it or don't.

Comment: @User Your " truth" says, that you a new in inequalities. The first step, which we make if we want to prove inequality this to understand, when the equality occurs. The proof is based on this. Sometimes it's another problem and does not help. But In our case it helps to find a nice proof. I took derivative before, of course for to understand  this.

Comment: If you took the derivative to understand that the minimum occurs for $b = 1$ you no longer need AmGm.  To understand how bogus this method is consider $b=\sqrt {{\sqrt 2+1}}+\sqrt {{\sqrt 2-1}}$ instead of $b=1$.  We can't get anywhere by writing $-33=-1-32$.

Comment: @User If we  want to get a nice solution we need to understand, when the equality occurs. Read my previous post. Stope with trolling.

Comment: Sigh. Users can see that not only your answer, but also the comments you write are troll and bogus. You said you took derivatives.  Where is this in your answer?  You yourself are calling me a troll by taking down $b=1$ from the sky.  Because I revealed this?

Answer (score 1):

We want to minimise $16x^4+(x-33)^2$, its derivative is $2(32x^3+x-33)$. This has a root at $x=1$ (either notice this or try with the Rational Root Theorem). Then we can factor it as $2(x-1)(32x^2+32x+33)$, and the second polynomial does not have real roots. In fact, the derivative is positive for $x>1$ and negative for $x<1$. Hence the minimum is attained at $x=1$ and it is equal to $4\sqrt{65}$.